# My ubuntu system not accepting password

Tags: password-recovery

I changed permissions of home directory to list files only after that when I restarted my system its not accepting my password which is correct one. So after that I searched for solution on internet to recover my password using boot in recovery mode still not any effect noticed.

Edited

Distro : Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Desktop

Comment: What exactly did you ro to change permissions? I suspect you irrecoverably broke your system.

Comment: You can reset the password in recovery mode. See this [this question and second solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).

Comment: I wanted that my home directory must only accessed by root user/authorized person if any unknown wants to access the file/directory then he will need to enter password. I tried it on directory which is under home directry and it worked. So tried same on main home directory and then I rebooted the system and entered my password after that this issue started not aacepting password. If system broked then How I can recover w/o loosing any data and apps installed on it?

Comment: @Tanvir Actually I followed this but no effect.

Comment: Just changing permissions will not make you lose data. Go into recovery mode and do `chmod 755 /home` and `chmod 755 /home/yourusername`.

Comment: check your locale (system, keyboard, etc.)

Comment: @Jos Thank you but by changing the permissions it still giving same results not accepting the password.

Comment: Which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.